# OpenGL ES glFragColor depend on if condition on Fragment shader in iOS

Tags: ios, opengl-es, fragment-shader, vertex-shader

I'm writing an app on iOS allows drawing free style (using finger) and drawing image on screen. I use OpenGL ES to implement. I have 2 functions, one is drawing free style, one is drawing texture

--- Code drawing free style

```
- (void)drawFreeStyle:(NSMutableArray *)pointArray {

        //Prepare vertex data
        .....

        // Load data to the Vertex Buffer Object
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboId);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexCount*2*sizeof(GLfloat), vertexBuffer, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

        glEnableVertexAttribArray(ATTRIB_VERTEX);
        glVertexAttribPointer(ATTRIB_VERTEX, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

        **GLuint a_ver_flag_drawing_type = glGetAttribLocation(program[PROGRAM_POINT].id, "a_drawingType");
        glVertexAttrib1f(a_ver_flag_drawing_type, 0.0f);

        GLuint u_fra_flag_drawing_type = glGetUniformLocation(program[PROGRAM_POINT].id, "v_drawing_type");
        glUniform1f(u_fra_flag_drawing_type, 0.0);**

        glUseProgram(program[PROGRAM_POINT].id);
        glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, (int)vertexCount);

        // Display the buffer
        glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, viewRenderbuffer);
        [context presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER];
}
```

--- Code drawing texture

```
- (void)drawTexture:(UIImage *)image atRect:(CGRect)rect {

    GLuint a_ver_flag_drawing_type = glGetAttribLocation(program[PROGRAM_POINT].id, "a_drawingType");

    GLuint u_fra_flag_drawing_type = glGetUniformLocation(program[PROGRAM_POINT].id, "v_drawing_type");

    GLuint a_position_location = glGetAttribLocation(program[PROGRAM_POINT].id, "a_Position");
    GLuint a_texture_coordinates_location = glGetAttribLocation(program[PROGRAM_POINT].id, "a_TextureCoordinates");
    GLuint u_texture_unit_location = glGetUniformLocation(program[PROGRAM_POINT].id, "u_TextureUnit");

    glUseProgram(PROGRAM_POINT);
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texName);
    glUniform1i(u_texture_unit_location, 0);
    glUniform1f(u_fra_flag_drawing_type, 1.0);

    const float textrect[] = {-1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
        -1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
        1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
        1.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f};

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboId);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(textrect), textrect, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glVertexAttrib1f(a_ver_flag_drawing_type, 1.0f);

    glVertexAttribPointer(a_position_location, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 4 * sizeof(float), (void*)(0));
    glVertexAttribPointer(a_texture_coordinates_location, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 4 * sizeof(float), (void*)(2 * sizeof(float)));

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(a_ver_flag_drawing_type);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(a_position_location);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(a_texture_coordinates_location);

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);

    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, viewRenderbuffer);
    [context presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER];
}
```

Notice 2 variables `a_ver_flag_drawing_type` (attribute) and `u_fra_flag_drawing_type` (uniform). They're use for setting flags on vertex shader and fragment shader to determine drawing free style or texture on both files

--- Vertex shader

```
//Flag
attribute lowp float a_drawingType;

//For drawing
attribute vec4 inVertex;

uniform mat4 MVP;
uniform float pointSize;
uniform lowp vec4 vertexColor;

varying lowp vec4 color;

//For texture
attribute vec4 a_Position;
attribute vec2 a_TextureCoordinates;

varying vec2 v_TextureCoordinates;

void main()
{
    if (abs(a_drawingType - 1.0) < 0.0001) {
        //Draw texture        
        v_TextureCoordinates = a_TextureCoordinates;
        gl_Position = a_Position;
    } else {
        //Draw free style
        gl_Position = MVP * inVertex;
        gl_PointSize = pointSize;
        color = vertexColor;
    }

}
```

--- Fragment shader

```
precision mediump float;

uniform sampler2D texture;
varying lowp vec4 color;

uniform sampler2D u_TextureUnit;
varying vec2 v_TextureCoordinates;

uniform lowp float v_drawing_type;

void main()
{
    if (abs(v_drawing_type - 1.0) < 0.0001) {
        //Draw texture
        gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_TextureUnit, v_TextureCoordinates);
    } else {
        //Drawing free style
        gl_FragColor = color * texture2D(texture, gl_PointCoord);
    }

}
```

My idea is setting these flags from drawing code at drawing time. Attribute `a_drawingType` is used for vertex shader and Uniform `v_drawing_type` is used for fragment shader. Depending these flags to know draw free style or texture.

But if I run independently, each time just one type (if run drawing free style, comment code config drawing texture on vertex shader and fragment shader file and vice versa) it can draw as I want. If I combine them, it not only can't draw but also makes app crash as

```
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
```

I'm new for OpenGL ES and GLSL language, so I'm not sure my thinking about setting flags like that is right or wrong. Can anyone help me

Answer (score 2):

So why don't you just build 2 seperate shader programs and useProgram() on one of them, instead of sending flag values to GL and making expensive conditional branch in vertex and especially fragment shader?

Answer (score 1):

Attributes are per-vertex, uniforms are per-shader program.

You might see a crash if you supplied only one value for an attribute then asked OpenGL to draw, say, 100 points. In that case OpenGL is going to do an out-of-bounds array access when it attempts to fetch the attributes for vertices 2–100.

It'd be more normal to use two separate programs. Conditionals are very expensive on GPUs because GPUs try to maintain one program counter while processing multiple fragments. They're SIMD units. Any time the evaluation of an `if` differs between two neighbouring fragments you're probably reducing parallelism. The idiom is therefore not to use `if` statements where possible.

If you switch to a `uniform` there's a good chance you won't lose any performance through absent parallelism because the paths will never diverge. Your GLSL compiler may even be smart enough to recompile the shader every time you reset the constant, effectively performing constant folding. But you'll be paying for the recompilation every time.

If you just had two programs and switched between them you wouldn't pay the recompilation fee.

It's not completely relevant in this case but e.g. you'd also often see code like:

```
if (abs(v_drawing_type - 1.0) < 0.0001) {
    //Draw texture
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_TextureUnit, v_TextureCoordinates);
} else {
    //Drawing free style
    gl_FragColor = color * texture2D(texture, gl_PointCoord);
}
```

Written more like:

```
gl_FragColor = mix(texture2D(u_TextureUnit, v_TextureCoordinates),
                   color * texture2D(texture, gl_PointCoord),
                   v_drawing_type);
```

... because that avoids the conditional entirely. In this case you'd want to adjust the `texture2D` so that both calls were identical, and probably factor them out of the call, to ensure you don't end up always doing two samples instead of one.

Comment: Thank @Tommy, I will try both of your suggestion, but what is the functional of 'mix' method, is it like if condition, just improve the performance? And can add I more than one statements on each argument of mix function

Comment: `mix(x, y, t)` evaluates to (if I've got them the right way around) `t*x + (1-t)*y` so if you allow `t` to be only 0 or 1 then it picks between the two without doing a conditional at all. If `t` may vary per vertex then it gives you picking without obstructing parallelism, at the cost of both options being computed. So it's a judgment call. But worth mentioning while the topic is open. It's one expression for `x` and `y` but you could just calculate them before the call to `mix`.

Comment: Thanks @Tommy, I separated into 2 programs with 2 pairs of shader files, one for drawing free style and another for drawing image. But I face an issue when drawing them together, seems they're conflicted. Can you see my latest post of this problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27535249/conflict-drawing-on-opengles-on-ios

Answer (score 1):

The previously posted answers explain certain pieces, but an important part is missing in all of them. It is perfectly legal to specify a single attribute value that is applied to all vertices in a draw call. What you did here was basically valid:

```
glVertexAttrib1f(a_ver_flag_drawing_type, 1.0f);
```

The direct problem was this call that followed shortly after:

```
glEnableVertexAttribArray(a_ver_flag_drawing_type);
```

There are two main ways to specify the value of a vertex attribute:

1. Use the current value, as specified in your case by `glVertexAttrib1f()`.
2. Use values from an array, as specified with `glVertexAttribPointer()`.

You select which of the two options is used for any given attribute by enabling/disabling the array, which is done by calling `glEnableVertexAttribArray()`/`glDisableVertexAttribArray()`.

In the posted code, the vertex attribute was specified as only a current value, but the attribute was then enabled to fetch from an array with `glEnableVertexAttribArray()`. This conflict caused the crash, because the attribute values would have been fetched from an array that was never specified. To use the specified current value, the call simply has to be changed to:

```
glDisableVertexAttribArray(a_ver_flag_drawing_type);
```

Or, if the array was never enabled, the call could be left out completely. But just in case another part of the code might have enabled it, it's safer to disable it explicitly.

As a side note, the following statement sequence from the first draw function also looks suspicious. `glUniform*()` sets value on the active program, so this will set a value on the previously active program, not the one specified in the second statement. If you want to set the value on the new program, the order of the statements has to be reversed.

```
glUniform1f(u_fra_flag_drawing_type, 0.0);
glUseProgram(program[PROGRAM_POINT].id);
```

On the whole thing, I think there are at least two approaches that are better than the one chosen:

1. Use separate shader programs for the two different types of rendering. While using a single program with switchable behavior is a valid option, it looks artificial, and using separate programs seems much cleaner.
2. If you want to stick with a single program, use a single uniform to do the switching, instead of using an attribute and a uniform. You could use the one you already have, but you might just as well make it a boolean while you're at it. So in *both* the vertex and fragment shader, use the same uniform declaration:

   ```
   uniform bool v_use_texture;
   ```

   Then the tests become:

   ```
   if (v_use_texture) {
   ```

   Getting the uniform location is the same as before, and you can set the value, which will the be available in both the vertex and fragment shader, with one of:

   ```
   glUniform1i(loc, 0);
   glUniform1i(loc, 1);
   ```

Comment: Thank @RetoKoradi, thanks for your suggestion, about approach 1, you mean I should have 2 programs with 2 vertex shader files and 2 fragment shader files

Comment: Thanks @RetoKoradi, I separated into 2 programs with 2 pairs of shader files, one for drawing free style and another for drawing image. But I face an issue when drawing them together, seems they're conflicted. Can you see my latest post of this problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27535249/conflict-drawing-on-opengles-on-ios

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, just change variable a_drawingType from Attribute to Uniform then use glGetUniformLocation and glUniform1f to get index and pass value. I think Attribute will pass for any vertex so use uniform to pass once.

Comment: You don't need a separate uniform for the vertex shader. You can use the same uniform in both shaders.

Comment: Thank @RetoKoradi, I tried to pass the uniform from vertex shader to fragment shader, but when running, it crashed at the line glDrawArray(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP)

Comment: You don't need to pass it from one shader to the other. You just declare the same uniform variable in both shaders, and then you can use it in both of them.

Comment: @RetoKoradi, so you mean I need to declare 2 variables on 2 shader files with the same name, and just pass data one time using glUniform1f

Comment: Thank @RetoKoradi, I will try your suggestion